# How to detect Outgoing links (apache,php..)

Tags: php, apache, hyperlink, external

I'm developing a website, but stuck at some point, where i needed to detect outgoing links on my website, and either forbid the links, or accept that, i don't know how facebook is doing this, but they can do it through facebook.com/l.php that if the link is marked spam, users will get notified about it.

I don't know if that's a php or htaccess, it worked in php using the DOMDOCUMENT, but it's not a real solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure how Facebook is implementing it, but what I would recommend is to use JQuery (or another javascript library) to rewrite all external links to a validating PHP script (e.g. Facebook's l.php script), w/ the intended url getting passed as a GET parameter.

Using JQuery, it might look like:

```
$('a[href]').each(function(){
  var safe_href = 'http://yourdomain.com/yourscript.php?url='+$(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('href', safe_href);
});
```

You can can then do a database lookup in yourscript.php based on the variable `$_GET['url']`, and redirect to that url if it's safe or display a message if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that you solve on the Apache or `.htaccess` level. Basically, whenever you're outputting a link, check if it's external, and if it is, change the destination to your redirector.

The redirector can then just check the URL passed, and if it's marked as malicious, it can show a message, and if it's not, then it can either automatically redirect or display some kind of notice that you're leaving the website.

Comment: i tried checking Links and could detect outgoing links before outputting them,using preg_match, but i couldnt find a way to detect and **replace** them, i'm not a pro using regex, any idea?

Comment: @Emad: I wouldn't use regular expressions to replace them; once you detect that the link is external, do something like `$url = "/r?u=" . rawurlencode($url);` (where `/r` is the URL of your redirector)

Answer (score 0):

`l.php` is a script that reads links via `$_GET['u']`. With the url in the your hand you decide where you want the client to be redirected.

So as it looks, you want the users to teach your application what is spam and what not. For that you will need a button "report spam" beside the url.

Comment: my question is one step behind this, as long as i catch all the links i can process them the way i want, but i cant reach this, so basicaly it has something to do with the server, php wouldn't be able to catch you before you leave the page thru a link, unless this link is modified to something else like instead of href="x" it becomes href="l.php?to=x" which i don't really want. i want to to happened behind the client side.